# React Native IOS Status Bar background

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar

Since Applying the backgroundColor props to StatusBar component doesn't get applied On IOS. I need to set the background colour of SafeAreaView to get the effect i want, it works fine but on iPhone X it will have that same colour at the bottom of the screen. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React-Native does not support background color change of StatusBar on iOS platform but on Android platform, it's ok (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#backgroundcolor). I wrote a work around for your problem. You can use it safely

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Platform} from "react-native";

const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight;

function StatusBarPlaceHolder() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle="light-content"
            />
        </View>
    );
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <StatusBarPlaceHolder/>
                ...YourContent
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**For SafeAreaView:**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Platform} from "react-native";
import SafeAreaView from "react-native-safe-area-view";
//You can also use react-navigation package for SafeAreaView with forceInset.

const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight;

function StatusBarPlaceHolder() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle="light-content"
            />
        </View>
    );
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}
                forceInset={{top: 'never'}}>
                <StatusBarPlaceHolder/>
                ...YourContent
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i got a problem with your code, I need to use the SafeAreaView, so i can adjust some layouts in iphone x. and if i changed the view above to SafeAreaView the status bar doesn't fit.

Comment: I added one more solution for safeareaview. If you use react-navigation in your project, you dont need to new package. Just import safeareaview from react-navigation

Comment: You' re welcome. If it worked, please give the green tick to this answer. Because if someone encounter something like this problem, they can try this solution. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, this works if the content is shorter than the screen size. However, If you have to scroll, the status bar background gets hidden. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2):

**Support for iPhone X**

In addition to **@sdkcy**'s answer, for **iPhone X** the STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT can´t be 20.

I solved it by installing the following library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height

**Install**

```
npm install --save react-native-status-bar-height
```

**Import**

```
import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-status-bar-height';
```

**And update the STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT like this:**

```
const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? getStatusBarHeight() : 0;
```

Finally, I also changed the height for Android to 0, because it was affecting the NavigationBar's height, but if it is working well for you, you can keep it the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone X uses **44pt** tall status bar

const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 : StatusBar.currentHeight;

Ref to these cheatsheets

- [IOS Design Guidelines](https://ivomynttinen.com/blog/ios-design-guidelines)
- [IOS Cheat Sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/iOS_Design.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support StatusBar component in React-Native like Android. Implementing the SafeAreaView component somehow lowers the view from the original status bar in iOS. I searched for many solutions and most of them guided to use custom components or use a library. Here's a quick solution that came in my head and it worked just fine. Just before the SafeAreaView wrap the total UI under a JSX fragment like <></>.

I am giving an example of my code so that you can understand better. I have tested this on iPhone 11 Pro Max and iPhone 14 and it works fine.

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  FlatList,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Linking,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
import {
  BackArrow,
  UserIcon,
  BellIcon,
  LogoutIcon,
  HomeIcon,
} from '../Includes/Includes';
import Colors from '../Components/Colors';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
const Notification = () => {
return(
<>
    {
      Platform.OS == "ios" && (
        <View style={{width: "100%", height: height * 0.05, backgroundColor: Colors.themeColor}}/>
      )
    }
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={'light-content'}
        backgroundColor={Colors.themeColor}
      />
      <InnerHeader />
      <MyView />
</SafeAreaView>
</>
)
}
```